# jquery, domain, get URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, dns

How can I get the domain name with jquery ??

Comment: I think my this answer is not found in web : If I want to get .com from www.example.com Try this code, and you will get "com". `var part = location.hostname.split('.'); var subdomains = part.shift(); var TLDextension = part.join('.');`

Answer (score 349, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for this, as simple javascript will suffice:

```
alert(document.domain);
```

See it in action:

```js
console.log("Output;");  
console.log(location.hostname);
console.log(document.domain);
alert(window.location.hostname)

console.log("document.URL : "+document.URL);
console.log("document.location.href : "+document.location.href);
console.log("document.location.origin : "+document.location.origin);
console.log("document.location.hostname : "+document.location.hostname);
console.log("document.location.host : "+document.location.host);
console.log("document.location.pathname : "+document.location.pathname);
```

For further domain-related values, check out the properties of [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.location) online. You may find that `location.host` is a better option, as its content could differ from `document.domain`. For instance, the url `http://192.168.1.80:8080` will have only the ipaddress in `document.domain`, but both the ipaddress and port number in `location.host`.

Comment: @rob.alarcon It's a [W3C recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-2250147) and has very broad support among browsers, old and new. The only issue I know of is that some browsers ([such as Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.domain#Notes)) will let you write to this property (readonly per the spec) as long as the new value is a subdomain of the original domain.

Comment: I would actually recommend using `window.location.host` (as bibby posted). I just fixed a bug where `document.domain` was being set to the root domain instead of the subdomain.

Comment: In IE11 `document.location.origin` returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 119):

**EDIT:**

If you don't need to support IE10, you can simply use: `document.location.origin`

**Original answer, if you need legacy support**

You can get all this and more by inspecting the location object:

```
location = {
  host: "stackoverflow.com",
  hostname: "stackoverflow.com",
  href: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300771/jquery-domain-get-url",
  pathname: "/questions/2300771/jquery-domain-get-url",
  port: "",
  protocol: "http:"
}
```

so:

```
location.host
```

would be the domain, in this case stackoverflow.com. For the complete first part of the url, you can use:

```
location.protocol + "//" + location.host
```

which in this case would be http://stackoverflow.com

No jQuery required.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549117/whats-the-difference-between-window-location-host-and-window-location-hostname

Comment: @ For the complete url, why not use `document.location.origin` which will result to [https://stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com). This method includes the appropriate protocol

Answer (score 33):

Similar to the answer before there there is

```
location.host
```

The location global has more fun facts about the current url as well. ( protocol, host, port, pathname, search, hash )

Answer (score 20):

If you need from string, like me, use this function - it really works.

```
function getHost(url)
{
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    return a.hostname;
}
```

But note, if there is a subdomain (e.g. www.) in the URL it will get returned with the hostname. Conversely, if there is no subdomain the hostname will not have one either.

Comment: Could @Vova Popov (or someone) please clarify the last sentence? "www. ar no www."?!?

Comment: He's saying that a.hostname will return the www. that's part of your domain.  So in other words, this would be false: `getHost('http://www.google.com') == 'google.com'` whereas this would be true: `getHost('http://google.com') == 'google.com'`

Answer (score 9):

You can use below codes for get different parameters of Current URL

```
alert("document.URL : "+document.URL);
alert("document.location.href : "+document.location.href);
alert("document.location.origin : "+document.location.origin);
alert("document.location.hostname : "+document.location.hostname);
alert("document.location.host : "+document.location.host);
alert("document.location.pathname : "+document.location.pathname);
```

Comment: is there also a way to get the host where the js file is hosted instead of the document? atm. i'm manipulating the js file server side to get this "connection" string which works but looks inefficiant since i would prefer a static js file.

Answer (score 6):

jQuery is not needed, use simple javascript:

```
document.domain
```

Comment: maybe it is not need it but saying like that you are not answer the question

Comment: Yeah, i'm not a robot that answers the question literally.  I answered the question pragmatically knowing what the end goal was and that you don't need jQuery to attain the goal.

Comment: I understand but that kind of answer is not complete, if you want you can do a better answer

Answer (score 3):

`document.baseURI` gives you the domain + port. It's used if an image tag uses a relative instead of an absolute path. Probably already solved, but it might be useful for other guys.

Answer (score 2):

```
var part = location.hostname.split('.');
var subdomains = part.shift();
var upperleveldomains = part.join('.');
```

second-level-domain, you might use

```
var sleveldomain = parts.slice(-2).join('.');
```

Answer (score 1):

check this

`alert(window.location.hostname);`

this will return host name as www.domain.com

Answer (score -2):

```
//If url is something.domain.com this returns -> domain.com
function getDomain() {
  return window.location.hostname.replace(/([a-z]+.)/,"");
}
```

Answer (score -4):

```
//If url is something.domain.com this returns -> domain.com
function getDomain() {
  return window.location.hostname.replace(/([a-zA-Z0-9]+.)/,"");
}
```

Comment: but if the url already dont have the prefix, it will remove the domain name..

Example: "stackoveflow.com" will become "com"

Comment: `Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.` - Jamie Zawinski