# Whats the difference between window.location.host and window.location.hostname

Tags: javascript

They both seem to give me the same thing (the domain name currently executing the script).

So what's the difference (if any) and where should each be used?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.location

Comment: **Specifically,** https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.location#Properties

Answer (score 89, accepted):

[MDN Web Docs - window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

`host....`: the host name and port number. *[www.google.com]:80*
`hostname`: the host name (without the port number or square brackets). *www.google.com*

Comment: In my firebug console I get the same though - `domain.com` and `domain.com`. No square brackets, no port number. Here is the code: `console.log(window.location.host); console.log(window.location.hostname);`

Comment: @Thomas it could be that the port is explicit only if it's non-standard (= not 80)

Comment: Fair enough. So, if I want the current domain name, its hostname. :) Many thanks - will accept as answer in 4 minutes! :p

Comment: @Pekka In if you have example "http://localhost:80" which contains port 80, in that case "window.location.host" and "window.location.hostname" are same because 80 is default port. If you have "http://localhost:54198/" you will have following results: window.location.host = "localhost:54198" and window.location.hostname = "localhost".

Comment: So then the difference between `host` & `origin` is that `origin` also has `protocol` attached?