# location.host vs location.hostname and cross-browser compatibility?

Tags: javascript, html, window, location, host

Which one of these is the most effective vs checking if the user agent is accessing via the correct domain.

We would like to show a small js based 'top bar' style warning if they are accessing the domain using some sort of web proxy (as it tends to break the js).

We were thinking about using the following:

```
var r = /.*domain\.com$/;
if (r.test(location.hostname)) {
    // showMessage ...
}
```

That would take care of any subdomains we ever use.

Which should we use host or hostname?

In Firefox 5 and Chrome 12:

```
console.log(location.host);
console.log(location.hostname);
```

.. shows the same for both.

Is that because the port isn't actually in the address bar?

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp) says host contains the port.

**Should location.host/hostname be validated or can we be pretty certain in IE6+ and all the others it will exist?**

Comment: One thing to note is that google chrome has a location.origin, where MSIE and Firefox do not.  https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.location - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms952653.aspx

Comment: See also: [Whats the difference between window.location.host and window.location.hostname](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549117)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Whats the difference between window.location.host and window.location.hostname](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549117/whats-the-difference-between-window-location-host-and-window-location-hostname)

Answer (score 1399, accepted):

[image: interactive link anatomy]

As a little memo: the [interactive link anatomy](http://bl.ocks.org/3070589)

--

In short (assuming a location of `http://example.org:8888/foo/bar#bang`):

- `hostname` gives you `example.org`
- `host` gives you `example.org:8888`

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Generic_syntax, the port should not be consider a part of the host (but it is a part of the authority).

Comment: @Alec this is an interesting technical note; drilling down thru the Wikipedia citation reveals that, [according to RFC 3986, "authority"](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.2) _ought to be the term_ for the concatenation of the hostname, `:`, and port. I wonder how much of the discussion is still available from when `location.host` was being formulated... I suspect it's named such today because nobody present had read or thought to mention that RFC.

Answer (score 78):

host just includes the port number if there is one specified.  If there is no port number specifically in the URL, then it returns the same as hostname.  You pick whether you care to match the port number or not.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location for more info on the `window.location` object and the various choices it has for matching (with or without port).

I would assume you want hostname to just get the site name.

Comment: The links is broken now :(

Comment: Use this instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

Comment: @Stranger - Edited my post to update the link.

Answer (score 37):

If you are insisting to use the `window.location.origin`
You can put this in top of your code before reading the `origin`

```
if (!window.location.origin) {
  window.location.origin = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + (window.location.port ? ':' + window.location.port: '');
}
```

**[Solution](http://tosbourn.com/a-fix-for-window-location-origin-in-internet-explorer/)**

PS: For the record, it was actually the original question. It was already edited :)

Comment: But.... OP never mentioned `window.location.origin` in their question. Their question was actually specifically regarding things that are **not** `window.location.origin`.

Comment: It's also worth noting that window.location.origin has browser compatibility issues.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 10):

Your primary question has been answered above.  I just wanted to point out that the regex you're using has a bug.  It will also succeed on `foo-domain.com` which is not a subdomain of `domain.com`

What you really want is this:

```
/(^|\.)domain\.com$/
```

Answer (score 4):

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

It seems that you will get the same result for both, but `hostname` contains clear host name without brackets or port number.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add a note that Google Chrome browser has origin attribute for the location. which gives you the entire domain from protocol to the port number as shown in the below screenshot. 
[image: chrome developers tool]

Answer (score 3):

From the mdn web docs you can see an [interactive location demo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location#location_anatomy) where you can hover over the elements to highlight their meaning:

[image]