# Changing HTML link based upon different parked domains

Tags: javascript, html, dns

I have around 40 domains parked to one website.

I have a banner advert showing 'buy this domain' with a link to my domain portfolio.

I would like for this link to be dynamically changed, based upon which domain the user has input in order to access the domain. I would specify the link directing to that domain's individual sales page, as opposed to the overall portfolio.

Any insight would be a great help!
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `window.location` to get several different parts of the current website url.

For full url

```
window.location.href
"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33484823/chaning-html-link-based-upon-different-parked-domains"
```

For domain only

```
window.location.hostname
"stackoverflow.com"
```

You could then use this `window.location.hostname` in the link you provide to your sales page (lets say www.sales.com), and pass it as a query parameter in the url.

```
// Navigate to sales page with domain as query parameter.
function goToSales() {
    location.href = "http://www.sales.com/?domain=" + window.location.hostname;
}

<a onclick="goToSales()">Buy domain!</a>
```

On the sales page you could then use javascript again and read the domain from `window.location.search` or any other prefered way to get query params in your server language.

For more examples of the attributes in `window.location` you can check this [interactive site](http://bl.ocks.org/abernier/3070589) as referenced from here [location.host vs location.hostname and cross-browser compatibility?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725890/location-host-vs-location-hostname-and-cross-browser-compatibility#11379802)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to examine window.location and parse the domain name from that, save it in a variable, then add it to your link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **location.host** to find the domain of the current page, and use that info in javascript.

```js
function goto(domain) {
  location.href = domain; // navigate to the given domain
}
```

```html
<!-- location.host gives you the domain of the page -->
<h1 onclick="goto(location.host)">Buy this domain!</h1>
```

I made a running example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/aC4Iy87WB5ay6Zj4ALAY?p=preview).