# How to access host from chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm looking for a way to read the current tab's host ([not just hostname](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11379802/1992055)).

I can read the url, but can't seem to find a reliable regex to extract out the host.

I can get the host from the window.location object, but I can't find a way to access that data from the extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given an URL, you can use the [`URL` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) to parse it and extract the [parsed URL components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL). For instance:

```js
// Just an example, there are many ways to get a URL in an extension...
var url = 'http://example.com:1234/test?foo=bar#hello=world';
var parsedUrl = new URL(url);
console.log(parsedUrl.host);

// Or if you want a one-liner:
console.log(new URL(url).host);
```

```html
Open the JavaScript console, and you'll see "example.com:1234" (2x).
```

Comment: Bummer that it's not a cross-browser functionality, since it's not stable in IE and some mobile browsers, but it serves my current purpose. Thank you.

Comment: @Pasaribu If the URL is absolute (i.e. a full URL), you can achieve the same effect with an anchor (`<a>` element). `var a = document.createElement('a'); a.href = url; console.log(a.host);`