# How to set a url base based on your host

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to be able to set a var urlbase based on my host. For example, I want to say in my service call,

```
    if (host ="localhost:8000") {
        var urlBase = '/api';
    } else {
        var urlBase = '/core/api';
    }
```

What would I put in the "Host" to check the host of the website?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `hostname` is available on the `location` global variable.

Your code might look like this:

```
var host = location.hostname;
```

I should also note that your code isn't going to work as written.  Your if statement is assigning a value to host with `=`, rather than comparing it with `==`.

More information about hostname at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hostname.asp) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725890/location-host-vs-location-hostname-and-cross-browser-compatibility).  See lots of details about the location variable at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location).

AngularJS also offers an [injectable service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) to allow for testing called `$location` that does all the same things.

Comment: Simple and easy. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In AngularJS you have the $location service

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

check for absUrl(), host(), and url() methods.

```
var host = $location.host();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the **$location** service provided by angular https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

```
function MyController($location){

    var host = 'http://' + $location.host();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.

```
if(window.location.hostname == 'localhost')
    var urlBase = '/api';
else
    var urlBase = '/core/api';
```

Answer (score 0):

we can inject $state in serice where we can see url an you can set base url