# Getting server IP within wasm application

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, ip-address, webassembly

I use C++ and Qt 5.15.x. I've built WebAssembly version of my desktop application.
The application is loaded using URL like "http://192.168.21.55:5555" (intranet application). I'd like to extract server IP address within WebAssembly application. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no solution for ip extraction,
but I've found the way to get host and port (host is equal to ip in my case).

```
#include <emscripten/val.h>
emscripten::val location = emscripten::val::global("location");
auto host = QString::fromStdString(location["host"].as<std::string>());
auto port = QString::fromStdString(location["port"].as<std::string>());
```

Comment: Small remark: Using `"hostname"` instead of `"host"` will remove any port number that might be specified. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11379802/6700329). For me, this was an important detail. Apart from that, great answer.