# Difference between host and hostname in window

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Whats the difference between window.location.host and window.location.hostname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549117/whats-the-difference-between-window-location-host-and-window-location-hostname)

I'm looking at the `window` variable using the console and I notice that there are two different fields, one named `host` and the other `hostname`. After I've checked a few sites, there seems to be the same value in both. What is the difference between them? Which should be used for what purpose?

Comment: If you're refering to `window.location`, I've always used host. I didn't even know there was `hostname`. Will be interesting to see what others say.

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location#Properties. It's a list of properties with examples.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

As specified by the [definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location):

- *hostname* is the host name (without the port number or square brackets)
- *host* is the host name and port number

So depending on your needs, you should use the one or the other. Most of the HTTP communication will go on default port 80, so you might omit it then. On the other hand, if you suspect that you need to take regard to non-standard port settings, you need to include that information in your source code as well.

Comment: So then the difference between `host` & `origin` is that `origin` also has `protocol` attached?

Comment: @Cody Where is the *origin* coming from? I'm not entirely sure I know which variable you're referring to.

Comment: @KonradViltersten https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/origin

Comment: Yes, `window.location.origin` also includes the protocol (with `://`).

Answer (score 23):

Say we have this example:

```
example.org:1111
```

The **hostname** is the name - `example.org`

The **host** includes both the host name, and any port numbers associated - `example.org:1111`