# How to read the current URL in the react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like read and print the current URL in the react application. Right now i am using "window.location.pathname" to read the URL but would like to know if there is a better way or some react way to read the URL

Comment: if you are using router, you can look at this https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md

Answer (score 22):

Suppose the current URL is `http://localhost:3000/question`:

```
window.location.href
```

returns the `href` (URL) of the current page (`http://localhost:3000/question`)

---

```
window.location.hostname
```

returns the domain name of the web host (`localhost`)

---

```
window.location.host
```

returns `localhost:3000`

---

```
window.location.pathname
```

returns the path and filename of the current page (`/question`)

---

```
window.location.origin
```

returns `http://localhost:3000`

---

```
window.location.protocol
```

returns the web protocol used (http: or https:) (In this case returns `http:`)

---

```
window.location.port
```

returns `3000`

Comment: Use `window.location.host` if you want the hostname with the port (e.g. `localhost:8080`), see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6549132/3253277

Answer (score 4):

if you are using React Router and your component is rendered by a `Route` like below for example:

```
<Route exact path='/' component={HomeComponent}/>
```

that component will automatically receive three objects from `Route` named `history` , `location` and `match` respectively. by that you can find what you asked under `location.pathname`. more info [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md#route-props)

if you still using react router and your component is not been rendered with `Route` , you need to use `withRouter` , which is a HOC and will give you `history` , `location` and `match` as props to your component. more info [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md)

if you are not using react router you gonna need to use `window.location.pathname` or `window.location.href` or only `location.pathname`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using react router:

```
const currentRoute= this.props.location.pathname
```

else you can get this like:

```
const currentRoute= window.location.pathname
```

href will give you complete url.

Answer (score 0):

We can get it from `this.props` using *withRouter* component from  **react-router-dom** package in the following way by adding in the class

```
import React from 'react';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Switch, Route, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';


class Application extends React.PureComponent {
  
  render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    this.props.location.pathname // we will get the pathname

    return (
      <div className='application'>
        {Hi}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(withRouter(Application));
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `useParams` hook to access values in your URL. When creating your routes in App.jsx you will specify the name of the input variable like this:

```
<Route 
   path="/search/:searchType/:module/:category/:search/:source"
   exact={true}
   component={yourComponent}
/>
```

Then you can use the `useParams` hook inside your component to access the variable values.

```
const {searchType, module, category, search, source} = useParams();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you using react js then use `useLocation` and `useHistory` hooks

```
import { useHistory ,useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
const location = useLocation()
console.log(location.pathname)

const history = useHistory()
console.log(history.location.pathname)
```