# How to get the current domain name a react app is running on

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apache

We have a react app running on multiple domain names, but I am unsure of how to get the current domain name in react.

E.g. The app runs the same code on www.example-one.com and www.example-two.com but using `window.location` or `document.location.href` etc just returns `localhost` as the app is served via a reverse proxy in Apache.

How do I get it to return `www.example-one.com` or `www.example-two.com`?

---

**EDIT**:
After some more testing the issue was because I was using `location.href` before the component had mounted. Moving the code to `componentDidMount` allowed me to access the domain name. Thanks for your help

Comment: `location.href` will return the domain, even if running via a reverse proxy.  It would be `localhost` on your server, but not the browser.  Unless of course you access the browser via `localhost`

Comment: Are you sure that wont work? Have you looked at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51988873/how-to-read-the-current-url-in-the-react-application

Comment: You need to separate your project into two different releases and place them in different folders with different config file.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I just tried again and using `location.href` results in the error `location is not defined` or using `window.location.href` results in `window is not defined` and the app fails to start

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve that by

```
const domain = window.location.host;
```