# Request Mapping on Spring by Javascript

Tags: javascript, spring

I am in a specific page and I have a function on Javascript:

```
function goToAnotherpage(){
    alert('goo');
    $.ajax({  
        type : 'POST',  
        url : "/firstpage",  

    });
}
```

In Controller I enter inside the method firstpage

```
@RequestMapping(value="/firstpage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView goToAnotherPage() throws ServiceException {
    logger.debug("IT ENTER HERE);
    return  new ModelAndView("/secondpage");
}
```

I cannot enter in the second page. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return the address and redirect in the javascript, something like this:

```
function goToAnotherpage(){
    alert('goo');
    $.ajax({  
        type : 'POST',  
        url : "/firstpage",  

    }).success(function(data){
        window.location.href = "http://mypage" + data; // http://mypage/secondPage
    });
}
```

Spring:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/firstpage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String goToAnotherPage() throws ServiceException {
    logger.debug("IT ENTERED HERE");
    return "/secondpage";
}
```

Comment: but, it must be automatically handled by spring .. i think that's what he was asking.

Comment: Spring as service not has the power to redirect some page. OP call the service and try return ModelAndView. Ajax request doesn't understand what's ModelAndView and he doesn't do nothing with the return.

Comment: window.location.href refers to the current page?

Comment: Yes. To another page it's used: `window.open(url, '_blank');`

Comment: The spring service received the request? And the ajax success received the response?

Comment: I had success. I was doing wrong things. You have to put localhost:8080. How can I put this dinamically?

Comment: url can be: `document.location.host + ':' + document.location.port + data;` see that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300771/jquery-domain-get-url